# Configuration for angular-translate not picked up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I just took over an AngularJS application and tried to translate the user interface with **angular-translate**. However, the text is not translated and I also get a strange sanatization message in the console.

This is my application:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('main', [
  'main.filters',
  'main.services',
  'main.directives',
  'main.controllers',
  'pascalprecht.translate',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngSanitize'
]);

app.config['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider
    .useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '/translations/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
    })
    .preferredLanguage('en')
    .useLocalStorage()
    .useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape')
    .useMissingTranslationHandlerLog();
}];
```

This is how I include the JS files:

```
<!-- Translation -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_resources/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_resources/bower_components/angular-translate-handler-log/angular-translate-handler-log.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_resources/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_resources/bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_resources/bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.min.js"></script>
```

This is one of my translation files (in `/translations/locale-en.json`):

```
{
  "foo": "Foo",
  "bar": "Bar"
}
```

And this is how I tried to use the translations in HTML:

```
<strong translate="foo"></strong>

<strong>{{ 'bar'' | translate }}</strong>
```

The only message that I get in my browser's console is:

> pascalprecht.translate.$translateSanitization: No sanitization strategy has been configured. This can have serious security implications. See http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security for details.

What am I doing wrong? Obviously, the configuration is not picked up at all?

Comment: looking at the error, you are missing sanitization strategy.. try with something like `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped');` maybe..

Comment: In the documentation, there also is ``escape``: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security

Comment: oh.. didn't know that.. may I know which versions of angular-translate you are using? can you put on a plunker with this minimal code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right, I missed a pair of round braces:

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider
    .useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '/translations/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
    })
    .preferredLanguage('en')
    .useLocalStorage()
    .useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape')
    .useMissingTranslationHandlerLog();
}]);
```

Now my configuration is picked up as expected.